# Use regex in meteor click handler

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm trying to bind click event of all elements that match a regex. There is a way to do it in jquery but I'm not sure how to translate the code to meteor framework. Here's the code I'm working on:

https://github.com/dnprock/leaderboard/blob/master/leaderboard.js

```
$("input:regex(class, inc*)").click(function(e) {
    var tag = $(e.currentTarget);
    ...
});
```

I'm binding to class `.inc*` with jquery. Is there a syntax for `'click input.inc*'`?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the CSS selector for begins with:

```
'click input[class^="inc"]': function () {
}
```

EDIT:

Contains:

```
'click input[class*="inc"]': function () {
}
```

Ends with:

```
'click input[class$="inc"]': function () {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of reactivity you need to bind events to document.

```
$(document).on("click", "input:regex(class, inc*)", function(e) {
  var tag = $(e.currentTarget);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say whether Meteor has a support for these type of syntax. But as an another workaround, I suggest you to use custom `data` attributes to specify the points of score to increment. see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FGlobal_attributes#attr-data-%2a). They can be retrieved in jQuery with [`.data(key)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

For example add `data-score` attribute to the `<button>` tags as

```
<input type="button" class="inc" data-score="5" value="Give 5 points" />
<input type="button" class="inc" data-score="10" value="Give 10 points" />.
```

And use those attributes like this:

```
'click input.inc': function (ev) {
    Players.update(Session.get("selected_player"), {$inc: {score: $(ev.target).data('score')}});
 },
```

Comment: My requirement is to use regex to attach to multiple click handlers. So this work around isn't relevant.